# Android mediaplayer no sound when playing local audio on some devices

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am writing program which plays music from the internet and download it, and if music whith music_id is downloaded it plays from the phone. I am testing app on my Galaxy S4 and all works perfectly, but when I tested it on LG G3s, music played only when it was not downloaded, after dowload player shows that music plays but there is no sound. A tested on other Samsung device (Android 4.1.1) works good. LG has the same OS version (4.4.2). Also I teted on Dell Venue Tablet, there is no sound too.

```
try {
                    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    String path = String.valueOf(root.getAbsolutePath()  + "/.music");
                    String localURL = path + "/" + audioId;
                    File file = new File(localURL);
                    Log.i("MediaPlayerTest",localURL);
                    if(file.exists()){
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(localURL);
                    }
                    else {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Double-check that the audio codecs from the downloaded file can be played on the device you are testing. That was our issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I added this premission but it still not working

Comment: On LG G3s works, but on tablet no, thnx. But i dont understand why on Samsung it worked without premission

Comment: can you add this function in your activity inside the onCreate method.

setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);